# Dynamic Binding arrays

Tags: java

Im having trouble with the dynamic binding feature in my program.

```
 Building[] b = new Building[3];//creates the object b
   b[0] = new Building(squarefootage, stories);
   b[1] = new House(squarefootage, stories, beds, baths);
   b[2] = new School(squarefootage, stories, classes);
   b[0].get_squarefootage();//calls the user to enter the area
   b[0].get_stories();//calls the user to enter the floors
   b[1].get_bedrooms();
   b[1].get_bathrooms();
```

I get the error for `lines b[1].get_bedrooms();` and `b[1].get_bathrooms();` that it cannot find the symbol get_bathrooms and get_bedrooms. I have these functions in the subclass `House` and have assigned it to the [1] slot in the array. Why does it not register the function in the subclass? Thanks for the help and maybe not explaining myself the best, Im new here...

Comment: This is because your array is of `Building`, therefore `b[i]` is a `Building` - not whatever subclass you put in there. If you want a `House` or a `School` you will have to cast. How would the compiler know that `b[1]` is a `House`? What if I were to do `b[1] = getABuildingFromSomewhere()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to typecast those values if you are using a polymorphic array.

```
((House)b[1]).get_bedrooms();
```

Polymorphism sounds like a very useful feature when you heard it at first, and it is very useful, but not as useful.